# Is there something similar to Linq to Entities in PHP?

Tags: php, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I really liked LINQ to Entities as well as the Entity Framework on my last project, I found it very easy to use and powerful, not to mention time-saving...

Now I have to work with PHP, is there something similar?

Features I am looking for are:

- automatic class creation from DB Model
- manipulate PHP objects in an SQL like fashion
- translation of PHP code into SQL queries

Any insight is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are quite a few ORM solutions for PHP, most famous is probably [Doctrine](http://www.doctrine-project.org)

I think you might find more info on this question: [Good PHP ORM Library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/108699/good-php-orm-library)

Also most php (MVC) frameworks come with some form of ORM bundled in.

Answer (score 0):

[Doctrine](http://www.doctrine-project.org/) is pretty close to what you are looking for. It works very well with [Symfony](http://symfony.com/get_started)